# Disable all checkstyle checks for a specific java package

Tags: java, xml, regex, checkstyle

I have two packages namely

> com/mydomain/abc/delegate/xyz/jaxws/managed

and `com/mydomain/abc/xyz/jaxws/managed`

I require checkstyle to be disabled only for the second package as these holds proxy classes that are autogenerated.

I use a suppression.xml as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC
    "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Suppressions 1.1//EN"
    "suppressions_1_1.dtd">

<suppressions>
       <!-- Suppress JavadocPackage in the test packages -->
       <suppress checks="JavadocPackage" files="[\\/]test[\\/]"/>

    <!-- Suppress all checkstyle for autogenerated jaxws.managed package -->
    <suppress checks="[a-zA-Z0-9]*" files="([^(delegate)])+([a-z]*[\\/]jaxws[\\/]managed[\\/])+"/>
</suppressions>
```

Please note the first suppression for disabling JavadocPackage check works fine but the second one does not. I am afraid that my regex for selecting the package might be wrong. Any help is much appreciated.

To state my requirements with an example:

The criteria for selection is that the package name should end in `jaxws.managed` but should not contain `delegate` in package name. More over `delegate` should come before `jaxws.managed` in the package name:

eg: checktyle checks in package `com.mycomany.delegate.service.jaxws.managed` must be enabled while that in `com.mycompany.abc.service.jaxws.service` must be disabled and it is to be noted that I do not know all the pakages names upfront except for this pattern.

Thanks and Regards
Sibi

Answer (score 19):

Just use the suppression:

```
<suppress checks="." files="com[\\/]mydomain[\\/]abc[\\/]xyz[\\/]jaxws[\\/]managed[\\/]"/>
```

Alternatively, I would recommend only passing the files you want checked to Checkstyle. For example, if you are using ANT, use a  to specify the files to process, and use  to specify files to ignore.

For example:

```
<fileset dir="src">
  <include name="**/*.java"/>
  <exclude name="com/mycompany/abc/service/jaxws/service/*.java"/>
</fileset>
```

Comment: Hi Oliver, Thankyou for the reply. Your solution works where the entire package name is known. In my case the criteria for selection is that the package name should end in "jaxws.managed" but should not contain "delegate" in package name. More over "delegate" should come before "jaxws.managed" in the package name: eg: checktyle checks in package "com.mycomany.delegate.service.jaxws.managed" must be enabled while that in com.mycompany.abc.service.jaxws.service" must be disabled.     Thank you oliver for pointing out this ambuiguity in my question.

Answer (score -6):

(?! delegate \b) [\/][a-z]*[\/]jaxws[\/]managed[\/]