# How to format a JAXB generated java class?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, checkstyle, jaxb2

My code fails due to checkstyle issues while compiling auto-generated jaxb classes. Any hints? Mentioned below is the maven error and except from my pom.xml.

**Error**

```
[INFO] --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.12:checkstyle (enforce-style) @ my ---
[INFO] Starting audit...
DefaultRole.java:42:1: '{' should be on the previous line.
RoleT.java:39:1: '{' should be on the previous line.
Audit done.

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Pom.xml**

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <schemaDirectory>src/main/webapp/schemas/</schemaDirectory>
                <packageName>com.my.schema.jaxbtest</packageName>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: I don't believe this would be a duplicate of the linked issue. I don't see how jaxb maven plugin and checkstyle are associated with the solutions provided in the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't bother formatting generated source code!

Instead, add a [CheckStyle exclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4022958/1050766) for the generated sources in the `com.my.schema.jaxbtest` package.

Comment: Thanks. That helps for now. But, in general, is there a way to provide formatting while generating the code? (Just curious)

Comment: @FarhanSyed Not that I'm aware of. This doesn't mean there isn't though! :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Appreciate it.